# Python Utilizing both MultiThreading and MultiProcessing in Python (Assistance Needed)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have a GUI that when you click the submit button it creates a multi-thread (so the GUI doesn't freeze), which calls a multi-process function, that calls a secondary function through this thread I've created.

I'm new to using Multi-Processing/Threading, and could use some assistance to get this to operate how I need it.

Currently when I run the code below, it doesn't perform the code within the function: apply_async_with_callback.  It only does the print statements within that function.  Within apply_async_with_callback, if I remove the args = (a_device, vpntermination), and put the two arguments into the second function I'm calling "start_commands" (start_commands(a_device, vpntermination)) it starts the code within all the functions but only performs one operation at a time when it should be doing 3 processes.

Long story short, I create a thread in the GUI, have it call the apply_async function, which this function performs multiprocessing of another function (start_commands).  I'm not sure if I'm missing something here on how threading or processing operates (I'm assuming I am as it's not performing correctly).

Note:  Without the threading, and if I just let the multiprocessing perform while the GUI is frozen, it works.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
class OutputWindowGUI(object):
  def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root

#Removed the GUI code that isn't needed, to shorten the amount of code shown.

    self.gui_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.apply_async_with_callback)
    self.gui_thread.start()



  def start_commands(self, a_device, vpntermination):
    try:
      self.net_connect = ConnectHandler(**a_device)
      self.hostname = self.net_connect.send_command("show hostname") #Used to store Hostname.
      self.output = self.net_connect.send_command("vpn-sessiondb logoff name " + str(vpntermination) +  " noconfirm") #Used for vpn termination command.
      print('\n******* Output for device ' + self.hostname + ' *******' )
      print(self.output)
      print('')
      self.net_connect.disconnect() 
    except (NetMikoTimeoutException, NetMikoAuthenticationException) as e: #Handles timeout errors.
      print("Could not connect to " + a_device.get("ip") + ", Error: ", e)
      print('')

  def log_result(results):
      self.result_list.append(self.results)

  def apply_async_with_callback(self):

    self.start_time = datetime.now()

    with Pool(processes=3) as self.pool:

      self.results = [self.pool.apply_async(self.start_commands, args = (a_device, vpntermination), callback=self.log_result) for a_device in all_firewalls]

      self.pool.close()
      self.pool.join()

    self.end_time = datetime.now() 
    self.total_time = self.end_time - self.start_time 
    print('\nTotal process time: ' + str(self.total_time))

def main():
  #Credentials function
  credentials()

  root=Tk()
  out_gui = OutputWindowGUI(root)
  root.mainloop() 


if __name__=='__main__':
  freeze_support()
  main()
```

Comment: Why are you spawning a thread to spawn processes?  Just spawn the processes.

Comment: As you can see what I stated in the beginning, " creates a multi-thread (so the GUI doesn't freeze)"...if you do not create a thread...with long functions...your GUI window will sit and freeze and show "not responding".  This eliminates that.

Comment: But spawning processes doesn't cause a freeze either.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are incorrect in this case.  If you spawn the processes within the mainloop of tkinter of my program it'll freeze up until those processes complete.

Comment: Probably because you are closing/joining the multiprocess pool synchronously.  You can let it run in the background instead.